# Why jQuery trigger method doesn't use native events?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

jQuery `trigger` works only with listeners attached by jQuery and won't work if listener attached otherwise (with prototype.js for example).

But, at the same time - if you trigger native event - it will works with both jQuery and other libraries.

The question is - why jQuery doesn't generate native event out of the box and instead uses its own stuff?

I'm just curious and want to know why it works that way.

P.S.

Sample code for native event

```
var trigger = function(el, eventName)
{
    if (document.createEvent)
    {
        var evt = document.createEvent('HTMLEvents');
        evt.initEvent(eventName, true, true);

        return el.dispatchEvent(evt);
    }

    if (el.fireEvent)
        return el.fireEvent('on' + eventName);
}
```

Comment: If I were to guess, I'd say it's probably for cross-browser compatibility reasons.

Comment: Beat me to it. My best guess is so that jQuery can be completely cross-browser compatible, and to do so, they need to aggregate all possible events from each browser into a single event on jQuery. Especially the events pertaining to mouse as each browser (*cough* IE) handles or provides each event differently.

Comment: jQuery's event system is an entire abstraction with a minimal hook into the native system. The reason was to deal with browser incompatibilities different browsers. It wasn't absolutely necessary that they make such a large abstraction, but that's the road they chose.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about why jquery did things in a certain way and not of a specific issue with code

Comment: ...it also let them implement non-standard features in their system. jQuery is basically built on the idea of solving standards non-compliance by creating a fully abstracted API that is non-compliant. So now instead of IE vs W3C, it's jQuery vs W3C.

Comment: See http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/4314

Comment: That's something you should ask the developer of jQuery.

Comment: Just to be clear, this isn't the case for every event type. For example, `.trigger("click")` on a checkbox will trigger the native click event so that it will change the checked property. https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.11.1/src/event.js#L601-L614

Answer (score 0):

In early versions of IE (before attachEvent/addEventListener), you could only assign one handler/listener to each event.  What jQuery does is assign a handler to the event, which calls a list of callbacks (the handlers you assigned).  This allows consistent behaviour of multiple handlers across different browsers.

Comment: jQuery isn't that old of a library. Both `addEventListener` and `attachEvent` were in existence when jQuery was released.

Comment: addEventListener wasn't available pre IE9.

Comment: Yes, however there are browsers that jQuery is designed to support that use neither the W3C model (addEventListener) or the MS model (attachEvent).  In cases like this the only option left is the .onclick, .onblur etc properties.  These can only be assigned one function, so jQuery has its own event system that is triggered by this single handler.

Comment: @user: What browsers have you got in mind which don't support either the W3C or MS model of event binding? All the browsers jQuery lists on its "supported browsers" (http://jquery.com/browser-support/) page support one of those models.

Comment: Like @Matt said, the supported browsers all have the methods that allow multiple bindings. But even if there was one that didn't, they still wouldn't need a full abstraction with a proprietary event handling system. They could emulate `addEventListener()` just as easily.

Comment: ...in fact, jQuery doesn't bind handlers if those two methods don't exist. [Here's a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3gxB6/) that squashes `.addEventListener()` before jQuery is loaded and then attempts to bind a click event. It quietly fails because neither `.addEventListener` nor `.attachEvent` exist. I put the `<script>` in the top panel and used `window.onload` for the binding to ensure that the order was correct. Also tested using jQuery 1.3.2, and it [behaves the same](http://jsfiddle.net/3gxB6/1/).

Comment: Ah, here's a [better demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3gxB6/3/) because it also squashes `.addEventListener` on `window` and `document`. Now jQuery throws a TypeError as it loads because looks for `.addEventListener` on one of those two objects while loading, and when it's it found, it assumes `.attachEvent` will work. So it actually hoses the entire library causing `$` to be `undefined`. Version `1.3.2` still fails silently though. Either way, jQuery only supports browsers that support binding multiple events.